# Upgrade coreutils on CentOS 4.8 server

Tags: centos, coreutils

I'd like to use the option `oflag=append` for a `dd` operation to append content to a file. This is to increase the size of the underlying file for a loop device in a case where creating a new larger file is too resource intensive.

*It's possible `dd` is not the best option for this anyway but is the best I am aware of. Better suggestions welcome!*

My CentOS 4.8 X86_64 server is running coreutils 5.2.1. The version of `dd` supplied with this version of coreutils doesn't support the `oflag` option. No newer version appears present in the official repo.

I notice the [latest version of coreutils](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/) is 8.5 and assume that somewhere between 5.2.1 and 8.5 the `oflag` option was added.

Assuming I need to upgrade coreutils to a version newer than that currently supplied with CentOS 4.8 x86_64:

- Is it safe to upgrade coreutils?
- Which is the minimum version required for `dd` to support the `oflag` option?
- From where can I get an RPM? I'd prefer not to compile from source.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any alternative methods to do what you want, offhand.

Upgrading seems dangerous; the odds are pretty much in favour of a backwards incompatible change, somewhere in the long list of binaries in coreutils. Pretty much every script on your system uses binaries from coreutils, so a backwards incompatible change in the wrong spot can wreak havoc on your box.

Next option: getting a binary RPM for this. I consider this not very likely, unless you build it yourself.

What you could safely do though, is build the coreutils source (never done that, but it probably is just a configure, make, make install) up to and including the 'make' part. *Do not do 'make install'.* Then, pick the new dd from the newly generated binaries, drop it in /bin as dd_new and you're good to go. Safe and sound.

That is, provided the new coreutils build on your old glibc :)

Comment: Brilliant - an excellent option for getting the newer dd without disturbing the current coreutils binaries. I agree that playing with coreutils is a risky process!

Comment: Playing with coreutils sounds like turning them into coredumputils. But yes, I was going to tell you about the "use the Source, Luke"-option, but wzzrd was faster than me. +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish the dd task you want with "seek" without having to build a new coreutils.

```
ls -l loopfile
```

Get the size, divide by 1024, then:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=loopfile bs=1M seek=1024 count=2048
```

(that's writing in 1M blocks, so skips 1G of the output, then adds 2G to the file.  Make sure the block size divides evenly into the filesize.  It's likely you'll need a 1k block size and a much bigger seek and count number)

I'd do some small-scale experimentation.  You might also need "`conv=notrunc`".